# How to make Python function which accepts tuple input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 2, this function definition is valid:

```
def sv( (L, R) ):
    return L ^ R
```

However, in Python 3, a syntax error is returned on the second left parenthesis.
I can't figure out why?

How do I instruct Python to accept a tuple as input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function parameters are given as single variable names, so you would do:

```py
def sv(l_r):
    l, r = l_r
    return l ^ r
```

If you want to ensure that this is a tuple, you can use type annotations and mypy

```py
from typing import Tuple
def sv(l_r: Tuple[int, int]) -> int:
    l, r = l_r
    return l ^ r
```

However this is probably not what you want. Accept two parameters and if you have a tuple to pass in, use the splat operator `*`.

```py
def sv(l, r):
    return l ^ r

tup = (1, 2)
result = sv(*tup)
```

---

Note that this sort of pattern matching isn't generally supported by Python as a language feature, unlike some other languages (Haskell comes to mind). What you want to do in Haskell would be:

```hs
sv :: Bits a => (a, a) -> a
sv (l, r) = l `xor` r  -- Note the pattern match here on `(l, r)`

-- contrast with a two-argument function:

sv' :: Bits a => a -> a -> a
sv' l r = l `xor` r
```

Comment: @ColinMac I think that [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) does that.

Answer (score 4):

Tuple parameter unpacking was removed in python 3.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/